# MYSQL query to be optimized

Tags: mysql, query-optimization

If I have an example query:

```
Select * from dept_emp where YEAR(from_date) = 2000 AND MONTH(from_date) = 4;
```

how I can rewrite the query to be more efficient without compromising its correctness avoiding a full table scan?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this would better use an index on `from_date`:

```
SELECT * FROM dept_emp WHERE from_date BETWEEN '2000-04-01' AND '2000-04-30'
```

Answer (score 0):

Use fewer functions in where clause.
Without using

```
Year(from_date) = 2000
```

You can directly state the year. Same for the month.

Use proper indexes for columns used in Where clause.

Comment: I didn't get you, can you write an example?

Comment: Check ceejayoz answer :)
https://stackoverflow.com/a/59271966/8309464

Comment: See "sargable" in Wikipedia.